# What is the difference of ".. let i = index" and "..let i as index"?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngfor

I am new to angular and I've been watching some youtube videos. Some of them use "let item of items; **let i as index**" and another one use "let item of items; **let i = index**". I tried to search for their difference in google, but I can't seem to find a simple answer. Can somebody explain what's the difference of the bolded codes? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just shorthand(minified code), for example this code

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

is shorthand code for this:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

So baiscally the are the same :)

Angular Docs : [link](https://%3Cng-template%20ngFor%20let-item%20%5BngForOf%5D=%22items%22%20let-i=%22index%22%20%5BngForTrackBy%5D=%22trackByFn%22%3E%20%20%20%3Cli%3E...%3C/li%3E%20%3C/ng-template%3E)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answering my question.

I'd also like to clarify some things above. You said it is just a shorthand code of the other. So basically, I tried a few things and here's what I got:

from the codes:

```
 <div class="todo" *ngFor="let list of lists; index as i">
```

and

```
<div class="todo" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index">
```

They yield the same result. But from my question, I wrote

```
<div class="todo" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i as index">
```

this will yield in an **[object]**

So, I'll assume that this code:

is just a typo.

Thank you for clarifying their difference. Really appreciate the help!